# Shapeless HList polymorphic map with an argument

Tags: scala, shapeless, implicits

Given an HList of `Label[A](String)` I want to map it into an HList of `LabelWithValue[A](Label[A], A)`, where the actual values come from a `Map[String, Any]`. In the example below I just defined the map of values in the method, just imagine the values come from a database.

The below works, but it is very veeery hacky because it uses a global var. Instead I'd like to pass the `Map[String, Any]` into `GetLabelWithValue`. I didn't find a way though, because the caller of `getValues` implicitly creates a Mapper, and at that point the map of values doesn't exist yet. I tried to create a Mapper myself, but my type level programming skills aren't yet good enough.

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.poly._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

object Main extends App {
  case class Label[A](name: String)
  case class LabelWithValue[A](label: Label[A], value: A)

  // TODO: avoid the horrible global state - pass in the Map as a parameter
  var horribleGlobalState: Map[String, Any] = _
  object GetLabelWithValue extends (Label ~> LabelWithValue) {
    def apply[A](label: Label[A]) =
        LabelWithValue(label, horribleGlobalState.get(label.name).asInstanceOf[A])
  }

  val label1 = Label[Int]("a")
  val label2 = Label[String]("b")
  val labels = label1 :: label2 :: HNil
  val labelsWithValues: LabelWithValue[Int] :: LabelWithValue[String] :: HNil = getValues(labels)
  println(labelsWithValues)

  def getValues[L <: HList, M <: HList](labels: L)(
    implicit mapper: Mapper.Aux[GetLabelWithValue.type, L, M]) = {

    horribleGlobalState = Map("a" -> 5, "b" -> "five")
    labels map GetLabelWithValue
  }
}
```

Here is an alternative implementation of GetLabelWithValue, which behaves the same way:

```
object GetLabelWithValue extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseLabel[A] = at[Label[A]] { label ⇒
    LabelWithValue(label, horribleGlobalState.get(label.name).asInstanceOf[A])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am by no means shapeless guru but here's first thing that comes to my mind:

```
object Main extends App {
  case class Label[A](name: String)
  case class LabelWithValue[A](label: Label[A], value: A)

  object combine extends Poly2 {
    implicit def workS[A <: HList, B] = at[Label[B], (Map[String, Any], A)] {
      case (i, (map, res)) ⇒
        (map, LabelWithValue(i, map.get(i.name).asInstanceOf[B]) :: res)
    }
  }

  var state: Map[String, Any] = Map("a" -> 5, "b" -> "five")

  val label1 = Label[Int]("a")
  val label2 = Label[String]("b")

  val labels = label1 :: label2 :: HNil
  val mapped = labels.foldRight((state, HNil))(combine)._2
  println(mapped)
}
```

I'm not saying there's not better way, but this seems pretty reasonable - instead of global state you capture it using fold and decide based on it. Probably gives you a bit more power than you need though (as you could mutate the map inbetween folds, but...)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the full solution (based on KadekM's solution) when you want to use it in a method. The hard bit was to extract the type out of the tuple (which is the result of the fold).

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._
import shapeless.ops.tuple.IsComposite

object Main extends App {
  case class Label[A](name: String)
  case class LabelWithValue[A](label: Label[A], value: A)

  object combineLabelWithValue extends Poly2 {
    implicit def atLabel[A, B <: HList] = at[Label[A], (B, Map[String, Any])] {
      case (label, (acc, values)) ⇒
        (LabelWithValue(label, values.get(label.name).asInstanceOf[A]) :: acc, values)
    }
  }

  val label1 = Label[Int]("a")
  val label2 = Label[String]("b")
  val labels = label1 :: label2 :: HNil

  val labelsWithValues: LabelWithValue[Int] :: LabelWithValue[String] :: HNil = getValues(labels)
  println(labelsWithValues)

  def getValues[L <: HList, Out, P](labels: L)(
    implicit folder: RightFolder.Aux[L, (HNil.type, Map[String, Any]), combineLabelWithValue.type, P],
    ic: IsComposite.Aux[P, Out, _]
    ): Out = {
    val state = Map("a" -> 5, "b" -> "five")
    val resultTuple = labels.foldRight((HNil, state))(combineLabelWithValue)
    ic.head(resultTuple)
  }
}
```